# Code sharing nativescript and angular material dialogs

Tags: angular, angular-material, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a web project that heavily uses angular material dialog. I would like to re-use the dialog components for both the web and the nativescript-angular apps. I have split the functionality for opening, passing and getting parameters and closing the dialog into two services as shown below:

**dialog-service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public openedDialog: MatDialogRef<any>
  ) {}

  openDialog(params: any, component: any): Observable<any> {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component,
        {data: params, width: '90%'});
        return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }

  getDialogData(): any {
    return this.data;
  }

  closeDialog(result: any) {
    this.openedDialog.close(result);
  }
```

}

**dialog-service.tns.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogsService {
  constructor(
    private modalService: ModalDialogService,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private modalParams: ModalDialogParams
  ) {}

  openDialog(params: any, component: any): Observable<any> {
    const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
        context: params,
        fullscreen: true,
        viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef
    };
    return from(this.modalService.showModal(component, options));
  }

  getDialogData(): any {
    return this.modalParams.context;
  }

  closeDialog(result: any) {
    this.modalParams.closeCallback(result);
  }
```

}

on the component where the dialog is opened, I have this:

```
import { DialogsService } from './dialogs.service';

@Component()
export class HostComponent {

  constructor(
   private dialogsService: DialogsService
  ){}

  openDialog() {
    this.dialogsService.openDialog({myString: 'hello'},
    HelloDialogComponent).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result.myString);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

`HelloDialogComponent` looks like this:

```
@Component()
export class HelloDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  myString: string;     
  constructor(private dialogService: DialogService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    const data = this.dialogsService.getDialogData();
    this.myString = data.myString;
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogService.closeDialog({myString: this.myString})
  }
}
```

When i run the web app with ng serve, I get this error:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData
```

I have imported `MatDialogModule` in the app's AppModule. How can I make this work or how else can share code (except the html views and the css) between angular material dialogs and nativescript dialogs.

Comment: If you have MatDialogModule in your app module, then that must be the issue. You would need an separate `app.module.tns.ts` that will not include web specific modules.

Comment: i've already done this the app module for web and nativescript apps are separate.